# NavigationLink Swift UI Not showing View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

When the App loads and it's checked if the user is already logged in, I want to navigate to the ListView without showing another view first where the user has to press some text to view the list.

`Text("Why do I need this? Why not just show the view?")`- Why is this needed? Why can't I just push to the `ListView()`?
import SwiftUI

```
struct ContentView: View {


    //MARK: Properties
    @ObservedObject var session = FirebaseSession()

    @State var selection: Int? = nil

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            Group {
                if session.session != nil {
                    VStack {
                        ListView()
                        NavigationLink(destination: ListView(), tag: 1, selection: $selection) {
                            Text("Why do I need this? Why not just show the view?")
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    LoginView()
                }
            }
            .onAppear(perform: getUser)
            .padding()
        }
    }

    //MARK: Functions
    func getUser() {
        session.listen()
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have a specific view first if you user is already logged in.

Why don't you perform your getUser() method within the SceneDelegate, and depending on the user's state, you set the first view, like so :

```
if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)

        var firstView = session.session != nil ? MainView() : LoginView()
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: firstView)

        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

Hope this helps man!

Comment: Thank you!! I'm working this out now. I did originally try to do this but wouldn't let me change the firstView from LoginView() to MainView() as they're obviously two different Types. However, why can't you just call a View from SwiftUI and present it? It seems something that is incredibly difficult to achieve.. :( So for instance, after the user has logged in, to then show the MainView() as the LoginView isn't in a NavigationView

Comment: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context. That what I get form the `var firstView...`

Comment: Indeed, SwiftUI makes things completely different regarding the navigation system. My way of dealing with those multi-types views is to use AnyView(FirstView()), AnyView(SecondView()) and so on, and play with AnyViews in my apps